# probability variance question

Tags: probability

I would be very grateful if anyone could kindly help me with the following question.

[image]

Here is my working :

[image]

I get q as a negative probability => something is definitely wrong. Could anyone please let me know where have I gone wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You know you can take a screenshot on your computer instead of actually taking a picture with your camera, right?

Comment: Someone sent this picture to me. It wasn't on my computer.

I apologise for the picture not being clear.

Comment: "Someone sent this picture to me. It wasn't on my computer" What? You want to solve the problem for other guy or what?

Comment: No. These are questions I am supposed to revise for a test. Since I didn't have them, I had to ask someone to send them to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically did it right, double check for errors. It's hard on the eyes, does it say $\sigma^2= 0.99$? It looks wrong... As it stands (as it looks), the minimum variance should happen when $q=0$, which gives $\sigma^2=2.8236$ .

Comment: Yes. 0.99 it says.